# How to read/display "\n" text in file as a newline?

Tags: c#, file-io, text-files, newline

I've recently started coding on C#, and I'm having a strange yet fustrating issue for my text-based game.

The text file won't print out my "\n" literals written in the text file as new lines. I can't put actual lines because ReadAllLines() won't split the descriptions correctly anymore.

Here's an example to express what I mean

In roomdata.txt

```
You see an inn to the east, the everywhere else is covered in nothing but trees.\nYoucan make out a windmill and a pond in the entrance to the village.
You stand in a flat terrain spotted with unusual colorful stones.\nYou can see a tower miles away. The village is east of here.
```

In main

```
string[] roomsdata = File.ReadAllLines("roomdata.txt");
Console.WriteLine(roomsdata[0])
```

It will print "\n" in the text rather than actually creating new lines.

Comment: It *doesn't* escape anything. If an "extra" \ shows up, it's probably by looking at it in a debug view (or is the actual content of the file)..

Comment: What about using blank lines to separate room descriptions?

Comment: I use "\n" in the text file and when I look at the output of the text it becomes "\\n" this it became escaped, funilly enough if I try to do "\\n" it trick the system so to speak it'll actually print "\\\\n", adding two backlashes to pair the two in put the in text file, I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Alex That is incorrect (or, as per above, it's being looked at using something - like the debugger watch window - that *adds* "extra" slashes). **.NET IO *does not* "add escape characters"**. Please correct this incorrect belief / assumption first.

Comment: @PeterRuderman that will not work the blank lines are already being used to split each description.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm more than willing to reword the question, but I actually don't know what to reword it to, I was sure it was adding an extra \, else how is it printing "\n" literally rather than interpeting it as a new line? Also, like you said it does appear that way in the debugging so I'm sorry I assumed that.

Comment: Are you looking to replace all occurrences of `\n` with newlines?

Comment: @DavidG Yes, what Selman provided works. So I'm assuming what I got wrong is that when the text file is read it reads the "\n" as "\\n" when I actually want new lines.

Comment: @user2864740 I rewrote the question, I hope it's more to your liking.

Comment: It is printing `\n` literally because it is *read as `\n`, literally* (two characters: "\" and "n"). This is what makes the title / initial assumption(s) incorrect. When C# *compiles*, the "\n" *string literal* evaluates into a string containing just the NL character; this is a specific context that treats "\n" specially, and is *not* IO and/or the file shown.

Comment: So back to the title: “\n” is getting read as “\\n” in text file?" -- no, it is not. Ensure the title accurately reflects the actual task, and avoids assertions, except where the assertions themselves are under question. The actual "question" here is something more akin to "How to read/display "\n" text in file as a newline?"

Comment: @user2864740, that's fair, but why does the solution use Replace("\\n", "\n") if it's not actually a "\\n"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Replace` method to turn literal `\n` to newline escape sequence:

```
roomsdata[0].Replace("\\n", "\n")
```

> The "\n" will get added an extra "\"

Nothing gets added to the actual string. Since the file contains `\n` *literally*, the debugger shows the escaped version. So it's `\\n` in this case which is displayed as `\n`.

If you  want to replace `\n's` with newlines, you should use `Environment.NewLine`:

```
roomsdata[0].Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: I think OP actually wants to replace `\n` with newlines, but it's really unclear.

Comment: @DavidG I rewrote the question hope it's more clear now.